# NetMeeting - Sharing function/button greyed out

Tags: netmeeting

I'm running Windows XP SP3.  Why would my Sharing button be greyed out?

As some background information, this seemed to have happened when I upgraded my laptop to Windows 7. Upon losing NetMeeting capabilities, I used Remote Desktop Connection to get connected to a Windows XP workstation so I could continue to troubleshoot tasks with other users using NetMeeting on the RDP machine. Now I cannot share my desktop using this method

Comment: As some background information, this seemed to have happened when I upgraded my laptop to Windows 7.  Upon losing NetMeeting capabilities,  I used Remote Desktop Connection to get connected to a Windows XP workstation so I could continue to troubleshoot tasks with other users using NetMeeting on the RDP machine.  Now I cannot share my desktop using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244449) this is an expected behavior:

> If you establish a connection to the remote computer by using Remote Desktop Connection, also known as Terminal Services Client, and then you start NetMeeting, sharing will be disabled.